# How to make plt.show() show figures in Jypyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm new to python and I'm using matplotlib.pyplot to draw some figures in Jupyter.
When I use plt.plot() it just shows one single line in one figure, but when I try to show two lines in one figure using plt.show(), nothing shows. It works for PyCharm but I don't know why it doesn't work for Jupyter Notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
y1 = X
y2 = X ** 2
plt.plot(X, y1, "g-")  # it shows y=x in one figure
plt.plot(X, y2, "b-")  # it shows y=x**2 in another figure
plt.show()  # nothing shows!!!
```

How to show these two lines in one figure?

[image: my Jupyter screen-print]

Comment: try adding `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Alternatively use a subplot.

Comment: Your plots have already shown, which is why nothing happens with `plt.show()`.  Place `plt.show()` in the same cell with `plt.plot(...)` to suppress the bracketed characters from appearing.  Additionally, if you're using Jupyter Notebook, use Jupyter Lab instead, it's the updated version of Jupyter.  Just `Jupyter Lab` at the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you use multiple cells for your code.
Try putting all your code in one cell.

Or at least

```py
plt.plot(X, y1, "g-")  # it shows y=x in one figure
plt.plot(X, y2, "b-")  # it shows y=x**2 in another figure
plt.show()
```

in one cell. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic declarative of IPython (which runs under the hood of Jupyter), just add:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

In a code cell before your plot (eg. with imports at the very beginning of your notebook). It will do the job automatically and you will not need to issue a show command to each figure.